# alternative to GAE Keys for mySQL?

Tags: google-app-engine, primary-key

wondering if the GAE keys (com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key) can be used with local mysql apps? I presume it's not possible, so if I define my primary keys in my models as `long`s, do I lose too much of the key functionality, like the `KeyService` and querying using keys ?

Thanks

Comment: how/why are you planning on running your app locally, and with mysql as the datastore?

Comment: I'm basically looking for a similar Jetty/Servlet stack. The reason is more as an experiment, just to see what it takes to fully transform the app.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not lose functionality. You can still query using the long keys and the performance is the same.

The 'Key' datastore type allows you to create keys based on a string. For example, you might want to create the key based on the user's email address. You won't be able to have this functionality with long keys.

But in most cases you do not need this option.